# Not able to pass StringIndexer as list to the model pipeline stage

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

PySpark pipeline is quite new to me .I am trying to create the stages in pipeline by passing below list :

`pipeline = Pipeline().setStages([indexer,assembler,dtc_model])`

where I am Applying feature indexing on multiple columns :

`cat_col = ['Gender','Habit','Mode']`

`indexer = [StringIndexer(inputCol=column, outputCol=column+"_index").fit(training_data_0) for column in cat_col ]`

On Running the fit on the pipeline I am getting below error :

`model_pipeline = pipeline.fit(train_df)`

**How we can pass the list to the stage or any work around to achieve this or better way to do this?**

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3999694668013877> in <module>
----> 1 model_pipeline = pipeline.fit(train_df)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    130                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    131             else:
--> 132                 return self._fit(dataset)
    133         else:
    134             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py in _fit(self, dataset)
     95             if not (isinstance(stage, Estimator) or isinstance(stage, Transformer)):
     96                 raise TypeError(
---> 97                     "Cannot recognize a pipeline stage of type %s." % type(stage))
     98         indexOfLastEstimator = -1
     99         for i, stage in enumerate(stages):

TypeError: Cannot recognize a pipeline stage of type <class 'list'>.```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below-

```py
cat_col = ['Gender','Habit','Mode']
indexer = [StringIndexer(inputCol=column, outputCol=column+"_index").fit(training_data_0) for column in cat_col ]

assembler = VectorAssembler...
dtc_model = DecisionTreeClassifier...

# Create pipeline using transformers and estimators
stages = indexer
stages.append(assembler)
stages.append(dtc_model)
pipeline = Pipeline().setStages(stages)

model_pipeline = pipeline.fit(train_df)
```

Comment: On Applying the suggested change too, getting the same error : `TypeError: Cannot recognize a pipeline stage of type <class 'list'>`

Comment: updated ans. I haven't executed though, but give a try

Comment: I fixed it by using below  : `pipeline = Pipeline().setStages(indexer + [assembler,dtc_model])`

Thanks for the help!